# why ViewStates instead of Sessions

Tags: asp.net

why we use to store data in `ViewState`? even we have `Session`s to do the same job?

```
Session["Data"]
```

vs.

```
ViewState["Data"]
```

What's the difference?

Comment: Session is killed after 20 minutes (default), `ViewState` is only available during the current page's lifecycle. So the session lives longer as it needs to be(if you compare it with `ViewState`). But `ViewState` is serialized into base64-encoded strings and output in the view state hidden field, so it blows the data is transferred between server and client.

Comment: @PatrickHofman but Question Seems to Be a Simple

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar: Then close the question as duplicate of any other, or close it for another appropriate reason.

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar: I am a Student. and the reason to ask on forum is to get Quick and Simple answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Session` data is valid only when the current session is active. Usually the server deletes the session after half an hour or so. The `ViewState` is available, even when the session is expired and you still have the page on screen. That content is serialized in the view, and it is send over the network every time you open the page, or send a `form` back.

Another thing is this: When you have multiple instances of one page where you want to keep a name for example, you don't want two open instances of the form share the same variables. Instead, you save it in the View, where you have it available for that page, and that page only.

Answer (score 1):

ViewState applies on the page you are currently in and is stored on the client machine as a hidden field __ViewState, and is encrypted with Base64

While Session is stored on the server and in the scope of the whole user session, it is removed when the user leaves your site and the session expires (by default 20 minutes of inactivity) or you explicitly call Session.Abandon() on logout for example

You have to be careful when using session that it does not contain big objects, as when there are more active sessions, the memoru will be filled up.

And be careful when using big objects with ViewState, as its stored on the clients and goes back and forth with post backs.

Answer (score 1):

```
**Session**



Session state is maintained in session level.

  Session state value is available in all pages within a user session.
    - 
  Session state information stored in server.
    - 
  Session state persist the data of particular user in the server.
    This data available till user close the browser or session time
    Completes.
    -
 Session state used to persist the user-specific data on the server
    Side
```

**View state**

```
    View state is maintained in page level only. 
    View state of one page is not visible in another page.        
    View state information stored in client only.       
    View state persist the values of particular page in the client
  (browser) when post back     operation done.
```